# QT5 unescape a string

Tags: c++, qt5, qstring

I have a QString which may contain escape sequences like \n, \t, \r, \a, or even \u00C0 (UTF-8).

I cannot control or parameter the source of the data which is delivered that way dynamically by an external process.

**Aside from writing my own routine** to search and replace all the possible cases, using regular expressions, is there a **simple builtin way using QT5 frameworks**, to replace these sequences by a value?

For instance, I want the string "bla\tbla\n"
to become in memory 'b', 'l', 'a', 0x09, 'b', 'l', 'a', 0x0A
or the string "\u00C0 la maison" to become "À la maison".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Honestly I don't know if there's an public unescape method available, but I wouldn't even use regular expressions for this. This is a replacament doable in one pass over the string (search on SO for some pure C++ solution; you'll just need to adapt the mapping of `\uxxxx` sequences into UTF-16).

Comment: You are totally right. I'll answer with my routine soon. I think I won't adapt the mapping of `\uxxxx` into UTF-16, and I think I'll do it in a c style way. I found a very interesting gnu lib called [quotearg.c](https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/grep-src/lib/quotearg.c) which seems to do exhaustively the opposite of what I want to do, so I won't miss a case.

Comment: Looks more like `printf` functionality. @peppe, I don't think it has anything to do with UTF-16.

Comment: @Velkan: I understood that OP wants a QString in the end (from an original string containing the escape sequences), and a QString is UTF-16 encoded.